# Obtener nombre de control pagina ASP

Tags: vb.net

Quisiera me pudieran ayudar con lo siguiente:

Como puedo obtener el nombre de un textbox de una pagina web .aspx para poder enviar parametros desde una aplicacion externa (Windows Form)

Actualmente lo hago por medio de la API Find Window y enviando tabulaciones o moviendo el cursor por coordenadas y usando Send Keys.

Pero creo que pudiera hacer esto mas simple obteniendo el nombre del control y enviar los parametros directamente a este.

Espero alguien puea orientarme con esto.

Saludos

DS

Comment: EL nombre del control? te refieres al ID del html? tene en cuenta que por lo que decis, estas buscando el nombre en tiempo de diseño de un control que no es tuyo y esta en otra ventana. No, eso no se puede hacer. Tal vez sea mejor probar un scraping de la pagina a la cual queres insertar los datos?

Comment: Scraping? No lo he escuchado pero si es correcto es el Id de una pagina WEB que no es mia por ello implemente una aplicacion con Find Window para interactuar con ella.
Como seria eso de scraping?

Comment: Scraping es que bajes la informacion de una pagina web, como si fueras un navegador, y en tu caso ademas que trabajes en ella como si fueras una persona. Que es lo que queres lograr al final con esto?

Comment: Basicamente no requiero bajar información de ella, si no introducir datos en ella.
Esto es para automatizar el trabajo al usuario, es decir evitar que el usuario introduzca datos de forma manual la cantidad de datos son variados, 100, 200, 300, 1000 nunca es exacto. Actualmente lo hago asi. Busco el nombre de la ventana de la pagina web la obtengo y pongo en primer plano posterior a eso leo un archivo de texto e introduzco los datos que hay en el a la pagina web.

Comment: Podrias probar simular el post que hace la pagina.. como si fueras la pagina.. y sin necesidad de rellenar los datos...

Comment: Simular el metodo post? Desde mi aplicacion?
Bueno tendria que hacer una pagina, para simular eso, no? lo que tengo es un WindowsForm.

Comment: Para nada.. una aplicacion de escritorio puede llamar a una web api.

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/91407/discussion-between-jose-daniel-solis-and-gbianchi).

Comment: Uff no puedo accsar al Chat estoy en el trabajo y me esta bloqueando el acceso.
Entonces la fucnion para hacer lo que mencionas es web.api?

Comment: No. lo que te dije es que podes acceder a una API web desde una app de escritorio. Esta en vos investigar cuales son los paquetes que necesitas y como se deben enviar los datos e investigar que hace la llamada.

Comment: Excelente, estoy investigando respecto a esto.

Comment: Tambien podrias hacer un js, que se ejecute en el navegador y llene los campos que queres. Ahi si podes usar los id de la pagina.

Comment: Pero el js deberia de estar del lado de la pagina (no mia)?

Comment: Podrias usar algun manejador de scripts como greasemoneky